# std::thread constructor (amount of variables)

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, vector, stdthread

Hello i have a little problem with my program (i want to multiply array by scalar).

Basicly i want to create a vector of threads that will do the multiplication staff (element by element)

Code samples

First mainImplementation function

```
void mainImplementation(){

vector<thread> threads;
vector< vector<int> > result;
vector< vector<int> > tab;
vector<int> temp;
int row = 0;
int col = 0;
int scalar = 5;

loadDataFromFile(tab,temp,row,col);

int availableThreads = thread::hardware_concurrency();


    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){

        for(int j = 0; j < col; j++){

            for(int t = 1; i <= availableThreads; t++){

                threads.push_back(thread(scalarMultiplication,std::ref(tab),
                    std::ref(result),std::ref(temp),std::ref(i),std::ref(j),std::ref(scalar)));
            }

        }
    }
```

}

now function that implements scalar multiplication

```
void scalarMultiplication(vector< vector<int> >& vtab, vector< vector<int> >& vresult, vector<int>& vtemp, int& i, int& j, int& scalar){

//...implementation
```

}

I haven't implement this part yet but i cant resolve one issue

In the line

```
threads.push_back(thread(scalarMultiplication,std::ref(tab),
                    std::ref(result),std::ref(temp),std::ref(i),std::ref(j),std::ref(scalar)));
```

compiler says that there is an issue there

"Error: no instance of constructor std::thread::thread matches the argument list".

I can't seem to fix this issue. I did read that i should pass variables to the function in thread constructor by reference, so i think this is not an issue here. I pass to the multiplication function 6 variables so it should be ok but it isnt and i have no idea what to do here...google can't help me too cuz i searched for similar problem.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: I get no error from GCC 4.6. Is it possible you're using an old compiler that doesn't support variadic templates?

Comment: I think `_VARIADIC_MAX` was `5` on MSVC.

Comment: (As a side note, launching a thread for every single element is going to be extremely slow; and launching several for each element is almost certainly wrong. You'd be better off launching a small number of threads, each of which processes some subset of the data.)

Comment: well i use Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 (from dreamspark :D) so it should not throw errors. Well ill try to do multiplying stuff by rows or columns :)

i tried #define _VARIADIC_MAX 10 and didnt help

Comment: (You also might want to fix the inner loop condition; if you get this to compile, then you've got a fork bomb.)

Comment: You probably don't want references to `i` and `j` as parameters, as their lifetimes are constrained to the loop body.

Comment: The problem says `std::thread::thread` - does this mean it can't copy construct the threads. Does moving them work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was as I thought,  Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 doesn't have variadic templates. The default is `5` so you need to add a `#define` to increase the limit (the max is `10`):

```
#define _VARIADIC_MAX 10
```

Comment: @tezaja: hmm, did you add it *before* the header includes?

Comment: well i guess i was wrong and visual had some bug that didn't show the error first, now it shows it again after using this define

http://ifotos.pl/zobacz/stuff2jpg_nanhwae.jpg/

Comment: @tezaja: Is `void scalarMultiplication(vector< vector<int> >&, vector< vector<int> >&, vector<int>&, int&, int&, int&)` declared before you use it (i.e. forward declaration)? It says `unknown type` meaning it doesn`t recognize it.

Comment: hahaha i had to move this function above mainImplementation function in header file, now it works, THANKS!

It is so embarassing to make error like this :) i feel ashamed